# Glassfish hangs after moving installation directory

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I know the answer to this, but I'm posting this here because as an app developer, I was burned by this problem several times and it took a very long time to find the answer:

**I've moved my glassfish installation dir**, and now it hangs on startup.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple strategies that you can apply to resolve this issue.

The quick and dirty 'solution' is to

1. Make sure the server is stopped.
2. Delete the content of the
   osgi-cache, by removing the
   osgi-cache/felix directory in your
   domain.  This is usually found in
   glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1
   (GlassFish Server 3.0.1) OR
   glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
   (GlassFish Server 3.1).

There are situations where this will damage your domain, since you can install OSGi modules into your server that do not come from the glassfish/modules directory.  To avoid this kind of problem, you may want to

1. Verify that the server is stopped
2. Apply [this work-around](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3a-moving-glassfish-v3.x-folder-p27784232.html).

Comment: Was intending to accept my own answer for this, but yours is clearly better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give credit, the answer comes from [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/moving-glassfish-v3.x-folder-td27767041.html).

Here is the executive summary, and what you need to do:

> I think you need to delete the existing OSGi framework cache, since the 
>   framework uses the location of the bundles as a key and moving the 
>   install directory thus changes this key. You should just be able to delete:
>
> ```
>   glassfish-v3/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/felix/
> ```