# Keep receiving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, jsf, glassfish, el

I tried to update my class to add a new property called email and when I tested it I got this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pagename.xhtml @30,121 value="#{department.department.email}": The class 'classaddress.Department' does not have the property 'email'.
```

But everything is OK in the class. I put the getter and setter, tried to clean all generated files on glassfish, restart the pc, pray, etc.. Nothing works.

I`m using a Mac Mini with Glassfish, Eclipse and Postgres.

I did the same changes in other pc and everything works just fine.

Just Information:

Property declaration:

```
@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
private String email;
```

Getter and Setter:

```
/**
 * @return the email
 */
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

/**
 * @param email the email to set
 */
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using eclipse plugin to do that. I have cleaned everything manually

Comment: are you sure your use the class `classaddress.Department`?

Comment: pretty sure. The name classaddress is symbolic to protect information of course, but I`m using the right class for sure. Like I said, I code in other pc and everything worked just perfect. Then I take the SAME code to OSX and the error persist

Comment: I`ve comment the line refered to Email on .xhtml files and Department class. But the error continue (but not refering to .xhtml file). I think its glassfish cache problem. Anyone??????

Comment: yes! sounds like a cache problem

Comment: are you using the server as eclipse or native?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from glassfish website and started it by console. I tried to download the zip file of glassfish again but all the same. This is driving me crazy x___X

Comment: this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300034/glassfish-hangs-after-moving-installation-directory

helped me with this problem, BUT (there is alway a but) I have to stop server >clean osgi-cache > start server EVERY time I make a deploy. Anyone know how to 'FIX' it?

Comment: write a script that does it for you

Comment: writing a script is just a work around. there is no other way to fix it? It never happened before, started yesterday